# How to prevent JFrame alert effect in taskbar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, taskbar, jinternalframe

I am a Java SE developer and our program only run on windows OS, the program need to open files and display in UI, we display the file contents in JInternalFrame and always `setselected(true)` when the file is opened.

Recently we updated our program from `JRE1.6.0_41` to `JRE1.8.0_144` for a major bug, and noticed that in JRE1.8.0_144 when our program(JFrame) is not focused and call `setselected(true)` on JInternalFrame in the JFrame, the JFrame would blink in taskbar, which JRE1.6.0_41 would not. Some of the clients think it is annoying because they have to open files frequently.

So the problem is:

(1) Can I turn the feature off?

(2) If I can't, is there an alternative way to avoid the blink effect while I can still `setSelected()` on JInternalFrame?

If I didn't explain it well, here is the sample code to demo the alert effect, please run the program and <strike>minimize it into taskbar</strike> switch to another window, then it should blink. I have tested it on Windows 7, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 and they all have the same alert effect.

```
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.*;

/*
 * Copy and modified by Oracle sample code "InternalFrameDemo.java"
 */
public class Login extends JFrame {
    JDesktopPane desktop;
    private int m_iFrameCounter = 0;

    public Login() {
        super("InternalFrameDemo");

        //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge
        //of the screen.
        int inset = 50;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(inset, inset,
                  screenSize.width  - inset*2,
                  screenSize.height - inset*2);

        //Set up the GUI.
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane
        createFrame(); //create first "window"
        setContentPane(desktop);

        //Make dragging a little faster but perhaps uglier.
        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);

        // Add new frame every second
        Thread addFrameThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            createFrame();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        addFrameThread.start();
    }

    //Create a new internal frame.
    protected void createFrame() {
        JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
        frame.setTitle("" + m_iFrameCounter);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setVisible(true); //necessary as of 1.3
        desktop.add(frame);
        frame.moveToFront();
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
        m_iFrameCounter++;
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //Create and set up the window.
        Login frame = new Login();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Update 01**

This is the update codes which take @camickr advice to add `KeyboardFocusManager` and `WindowListener`, only `setselected(true)` on JInternalFrame when JFrame has focus or JFrame gain focus, but the alert still happen if you switch windows frequently, I think it is because JFrame lost focus right before `setselected(true)` on JInternalFrame. Maybe there is a way to improve the code?

```
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;

/*
 * Copy and modified by Oracle sample code "InternalFrameDemo.java"
 */
public class Login extends JFrame {
    JDesktopPane desktop;
    private int m_iFrameCounter = 0;
    private JInternalFrame m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = null;

    public Login() {
        super("InternalFrameDemo");

        //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge
        //of the screen.
        int inset = 50;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(inset, inset,
                  screenSize.width  - inset*2,
                  screenSize.height - inset*2);

        //Set up the GUI.
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane
        createFrame(); //create first "window"
        setContentPane(desktop);

        //Make dragging a little faster but perhaps uglier.
        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);

        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/ 
        //Add window listener to set last JInternalframe selected when JFrame activated
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                if (m_InternalFrameWaitSelected != null) {
                    try {
                        m_InternalFrameWaitSelected.setSelected(true);
                    } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }

        });
        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/

        // Add new frame every 50 millisecond
        Thread addFrameThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            createFrame();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        addFrameThread.start();
    }

    //Create a new internal frame.
    protected void createFrame() {
        JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
        frame.setTitle("" + m_iFrameCounter);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setVisible(true); //necessary as of 1.3
        desktop.add(frame);
        frame.moveToFront();
        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/
        // Only setselect(true) when JFrame is focus owner
        if (KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner() != null &&
                SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner(), this)) {
            try {
                frame.setSelected(true);
            } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
        } else {
            m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = frame;
        }
        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/
        m_iFrameCounter++;
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //Create and set up the window.
        Login frame = new Login();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Update 02**

Tried with `getGlobalActiveWindow()` and `windowActivated/windowDeactivated`, alert still happen if switch windows frequently. Below are the test code:

**getGlobalActiveWindow()**

```
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;

/*
 * Copy and modified by Oracle sample code "InternalFrameDemo.java"
 */
public class Login extends JFrame {
    JDesktopPane desktop;
    private int m_iFrameCounter = 0;
    private JInternalFrame m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = null;
    /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/ 
    private MyDefaultKeyboardFocusManager m_MyKeyboardFocusManager = new MyDefaultKeyboardFocusManager();

    public class MyDefaultKeyboardFocusManager extends DefaultKeyboardFocusManager {

        //The method is protected, need to add public method to call it
        public Window myGetGlobalActiveWindow() {
            return this.getGlobalActiveWindow();
        }

    }
    /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/ 

    public Login() {
        super("InternalFrameDemo");

        //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge
        //of the screen.
        int inset = 50;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(inset, inset,
                  screenSize.width  - inset*2,
                  screenSize.height - inset*2);

        //Set up the GUI.
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane
        setContentPane(desktop);

        //Make dragging a little faster but perhaps uglier.
        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);

        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/ 
        KeyboardFocusManager.setCurrentKeyboardFocusManager(m_MyKeyboardFocusManager);
        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/

        //Add window listener to set last JInternalframe selected when JFrame activated
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                if (m_InternalFrameWaitSelected != null) {
                    try {
                        m_InternalFrameWaitSelected.setSelected(true);
                    } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }

        });

        // Add new frame every 50 millisecond
        Thread addFrameThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            createFrame();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        addFrameThread.start();
    }

    //Create a new internal frame.
    protected void createFrame() {
        JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
        frame.setTitle("" + m_iFrameCounter);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setVisible(true); //necessary as of 1.3
        desktop.add(frame);
        frame.moveToFront();
        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/
        // Only setselect(true) when JFrame is active
        if (m_MyKeyboardFocusManager.myGetGlobalActiveWindow() == this) {
            try {
                frame.setSelected(true);
            } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
        } else {
            m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = frame;
        }
        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/
        m_iFrameCounter++;
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //Create and set up the window.
        Login frame = new Login();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**windowActivated/windowDeactivated**

```
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;

/*
 * Copy and modified by Oracle sample code "InternalFrameDemo.java"
 */
public class Login extends JFrame {
    JDesktopPane desktop;
    private int m_iFrameCounter = 0;
    private JInternalFrame m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = null;
    /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/ 
    private boolean m_bIsFrameActive = false;
    /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/ 

    public Login() {
        super("InternalFrameDemo");

        //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge
        //of the screen.
        int inset = 50;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(inset, inset,
                  screenSize.width  - inset*2,
                  screenSize.height - inset*2);

        //Set up the GUI.
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane
        setContentPane(desktop);

        //Make dragging a little faster but perhaps uglier.
        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);

        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/ 
        //Add window listener to set last JInternalframe selected when JFrame activated
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                m_bIsFrameActive = true;
                if (m_InternalFrameWaitSelected != null) {
                    try {
                        m_InternalFrameWaitSelected.setSelected(true);
                    } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                m_bIsFrameActive = false;
            }

        });
        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/

        // Add new frame every 50 millisecond
        Thread addFrameThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            createFrame();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        addFrameThread.start();
    }

    //Create a new internal frame.
    protected void createFrame() {
        JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
        frame.setTitle("" + m_iFrameCounter);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setVisible(true); //necessary as of 1.3
        desktop.add(frame);
        frame.moveToFront();
        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/
        // Only setselect(true) when JFrame is active
        if (m_bIsFrameActive) {
            try {
                frame.setSelected(true);
            } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
        } else {
            m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = frame;
        }
        /*********************************************  update codes *********************************************/
        m_iFrameCounter++;
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //Create and set up the window.
        Login frame = new Login();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If having no taskbar icon is an option use `JDialog` instead of `JFrame`. (I added Swing tag to the question, so most likely you'll get better options from the Swing guru's on SO. )

Comment: I think this is cool feature provided by windows. whenever the frame has change their state, it blinks to notify the user. However once you open your window, it will stop blinking. Why do you want to turn off this feature ?

Comment: @Shahid Because some of our clients need to open a lot of files in one time, during the files opening they will do something else which cause our program lose focus, then our program keep blinking which make our clients feel annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is interested about the answer, after I trace down to the source code in JInternalFrame, I find out the blink effect is caused by `requestFocus()` when `setSelected(true)` is called, so I decided to inherit JInternalFrame and replace `requestFocus()` with `requestFocusInWindow()`, now the blink effect is gone.

**Here is my final solution for the issue:**

```
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import sun.swing.SwingUtilities2;

import javax.swing.InternalFrameFocusTraversalPolicy;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;

/*
 * Copy and modified by Oracle sample code "InternalFrameDemo.java"
 */
public class Login extends JFrame {
    JDesktopPane desktop;
    private int m_iFrameCounter = 0;

    /**
     * This class is created to handle problem that program would blink in taskbar 
     * when call setSelected(true) on JInternalFrame base on JRE1.8.0_144, the only different content is
     * use lastFocusOwner.requestFocusInWindow(); instead of lastFocusOwner.requestFocus(); 
     * in method restoreSubcomponentFocus() 
     *
     */
    public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

        private Component lastFocusOwner;
        private final String BASE_JRE_VERSION = "1.8.0_144";

        public MyInternalFrame() {
            _checkJavaVersion();
        }

        public MyInternalFrame(String title) {
            super(title);
            _checkJavaVersion();
        }

        public MyInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable) {
            super(title, resizable);
            _checkJavaVersion();
        }

        public MyInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable) {
            super(title, resizable, closable);
            _checkJavaVersion();
        }

        public MyInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable, boolean maximizable) {
            super(title, resizable, closable, maximizable);
            _checkJavaVersion();
        }

        public MyInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable, boolean maximizable, boolean iconifiable) {
            super(title, resizable, closable, maximizable, iconifiable);
            _checkJavaVersion();
        }

        private void _checkJavaVersion() {
            if (!BASE_JRE_VERSION.equals(System.getProperty("java.version")))
                System.err.println(String.format("%s is not compatible with current Java runtime version : %s ", this.getClass().toString(), System.getProperty("java.version")));
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreSubcomponentFocus() {
            if (isIcon()) {
                SwingUtilities2.compositeRequestFocus(getDesktopIcon());
            }
            else {
                Component component = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getPermanentFocusOwner();
                if ((component == null) || !SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(component, this)) {
                    // FocusPropertyChangeListener will eventually update
                    // lastFocusOwner. As focus requests are asynchronous
                    // lastFocusOwner may be accessed before it has been correctly
                    // updated. To avoid any problems, lastFocusOwner is immediately
                    // set, assuming the request will succeed.
                    setLastFocusOwner(getMostRecentFocusOwner());
                    if (lastFocusOwner == null) {
                        // Make sure focus is restored somewhere, so that
                        // we don't leave a focused component in another frame while
                        // this frame is selected.
                        setLastFocusOwner(getContentPane());
                    }
                    lastFocusOwner.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            }
        }

        private void setLastFocusOwner(Component component) {
            lastFocusOwner = component;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getMostRecentFocusOwner() {
            if (isSelected()) {
                return getFocusOwner();
            }

            if (lastFocusOwner != null) {
                return lastFocusOwner;
            }

            FocusTraversalPolicy policy = getFocusTraversalPolicy();
            if (policy instanceof InternalFrameFocusTraversalPolicy) {
                return ((InternalFrameFocusTraversalPolicy)policy).
                    getInitialComponent(this);
            }

            Component toFocus = policy.getDefaultComponent(this);
            if (toFocus != null) {
                return toFocus;
            }
            return getContentPane();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getFocusOwner() {
            if (isSelected()) {
                return lastFocusOwner;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Login() {
        super("InternalFrameDemo");

        //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge
        //of the screen.
        int inset = 50;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(inset, inset,
                  screenSize.width  - inset*2,
                  screenSize.height - inset*2);

        //Set up the GUI.
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane
        setContentPane(desktop);

        //Make dragging a little faster but perhaps uglier.
        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);

        // Add new frame every 50 millisecond
        Thread addFrameThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            createFrame();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        addFrameThread.start();
    }

    //Create a new internal frame.
    protected void createFrame() {
        JInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
        frame.setTitle("" + m_iFrameCounter);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setVisible(true); //necessary as of 1.3
        desktop.add(frame);
        frame.moveToFront();
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
        m_iFrameCounter++;
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //Create and set up the window.
        Login frame = new Login();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> we display the file contents in JInternalFrame and always setselected(true) when the file is opened.

Don't know how to stop the blinking on the taskbar, but you can change the behaviour by not automatically invoking setSelected().

You could for example:

1. only invoke `setSelected()` when the frame is the active window. You can use the `KeyboardFocusManager` to check if the window is focused.
2. add a `WindowListener` to the frame and handle the `windowActivated` event to invoke the setSelected() method on the most recently opened internal frame.

Edit:

> run the program and minimize it into taskbar,

First I want to clarify that if I minimize the frame to the taskbar there is no problem with the icon blinking.

The icon only blinks if I click on another application and the Login frame loses focus while it is still open.

> the alert still happen if you switch windows frequently,

I changed your code to:

```
//if (KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner() != null &&
//    SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner(), this)) {
if (KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getActiveWindow() == this)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("active");
        frame.setSelected(true);
    }
    catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
}
else
{
    System.out.println("not");
//  frame = m_InternalFrameWaitSelected;
    m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = frame;
}
```

and I noticed that sometimes "active" was being displayed at even though is was playing a game in another window. So for some reason the KeyboardFocusManager was returning an incorrect value (or I don't understand how the method should work?)

So maybe you can try using the `getGlobalActiveWindow()` method to see if it makes any difference.

If not, then my next suggestion is to forget about the KeyboardFocusManager and manage a Boolean variable that indicates if your frame is active or not. So you would set the variable true in windowActivated and false in windowDeactivated. Then you test this variable when you create the frame.

Also note how I changed the following code:

```
//  frame = m_InternalFrameWaitSelected;
    m_InternalFrameWaitSelected = frame;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I added `KeyboardFocusManager` and `WindowListener` into my code, please see my update.

Comment: Thank you, `frame = m_InternalFrameWaitSelected;` is a stupid mistake and I corrected it. I added `getGlobalActiveWindow()` and 
 `windowActivated/windowDeactivated` test code, please see my update.

Comment: @exister, I just noticed, the JFrame has an `isActive()` method. Maybe that will work better than using the KeyboardFocusManager. If still having problems then I have no ideas. The key concept in my suggestions is to know when the frame is active and when it isn't. If the methods suggested here or the window listener don't provide you with the proper state of the Window then that seems to be to be a Java problem and I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: Tried JFrame `isActive()` and still don't work properly, anyway, it is good to have your help, thank you.